# How to force browser to download file using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, download

I'd like to let users to download images by clicking on a download icon:

The  image file is already fetched from the server and displayed:

```
<img  :src="currentMediaUrl">
```

The button is intended to force the browser to download the image above:

```
 <i @click="downloadMedia(currentMediaUrl)" class="fa fa-download"> </i>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
downloadMedia(media) {
  let uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(media);
  window.open(uriContent, 'neuesDokument');

},
```

But it downloads a file containing the media URI instead of the very file.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to download the file on click and this helped.

Answer (score 1):

That's a normal behavior, considering that you're encoding the URL itself instead of its content.

You can get desired result another way:

```html
<a :href="currentMediaUrl" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Comment: Does not work. Also the class need a `"` at the end.

Comment: Alright. Please refer to my comment on other answer on why it does not work for me.

Comment: In my case this works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would do this the same way you would in normal html5, namely by using a link element, setting the `download` attribute and... voila!

```html
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAAnElEQVR42u3RAQ0AAAgDIE1u9FvDOahAJzXFGS1ECEKEIEQIQoQgRIgQIQgRghAhCBGCECEIQYgQhAhBiBCECEEIQoQgRAhChCBECEIQIgQhQhAiBCFCEIIQIQgRghAhCBGCEIQIQYgQhAhBiBCEIEQIQoQgRAhChCAEIUIQIgQhQhAiBCEIEYIQIQgRghAhCBEiRAhChCBECEK+W0L3+TnU7375AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
  download="myImage.png"
  target="_blank"
>
  Download
</a>
```

In your case it would be:

```
<a :href="currentMediaUrl" download="myPrettyFileName.png">
  <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</a>
```

Comment: This works but not as intended. My image is displayed inside a `modal` gallery. I want the file just being downloaded, not being displayed instead of the modal.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. [The download attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) is pretty universally supported, except for safari on iphone and internet explorer. On those browsers this will result in a (new) page being opened to display the image. You could combine it with `target="_blank"` to force to open a new page if `download` is not supported. That sounds like a reasonable trade-off to me. If you don't want to download something else, just replace `currentMediaUrl`. If you mean something else, I am confused by what that is.

Comment: I'm developing on Chrome browser. After adding `target="_blank"` to the `a` link, when it is clicked, the image is opened in a new tab and the active window becomes the new tab. What I want is the browser to just download the file, without displaying it.

Comment: If you run the code snippet above and click "Download", does it download a 100x100 semi-transparent square, or does it show you an image somehow?

Comment: When I click the download link in the snippet above, it displays a dialog box, to choose whether I want to open or save `myimage.png`. That's not what I want. I want the browser just downloads the image quietly.

Comment: That download dialog is a browser setting. Afaik you cannot bypass that, nor do you want to bypass that. Since the example works, I am guessing that you did not correctly implement the download link. Inspect the generated html and verify that the `download` attribute is on the html. Also verify that you do not have click handlers interfering with the native behaviour of the download link.